# Display DB Entries in json Array in Controller (Laravel / PHP)

Tags: php, json, database, laravel

I am trying to write an index function in my PlayerController, so my Vue Component is able to create an array with userId, userName, userVote in this form: [{userId:1, userName:Jimmy,userVote:7},{}...]

I have a Players Table and Session Table, because my Player.userSession and Session.sessionId have the same attribute, I am using Laravel's request to fetch this information, create a variable with the other class with Session's ID and get all user who are part of the room.

Everything should be saved && returned back.

This is my code so far:

```
 public function index(Request $request)
    {


        $room = $request->input('sessionId');

        $currentPlayers = Player::where('userSession', $room)->get();

        $userId = $currentPlayers->userId;
        $userName = $currentPlayers->userName;
        $userVote = $currentPlayers->userVote;


        return json_encode([
        'userId' => $userId,
        'userName' => $userName,
        'userVote' => $userVote]);

    }
```

But now it says it : "Property [userId] does not exist on this collection instance."

https://pasteboard.co/IyJyUZ0.png
https://pasteboard.co/IyJypj5.png

Comment: `->get();` returns a collection of rows, you mean `->first();`? Alternatively, you could loop through the collection and then manipulate each one individually.

Comment: Yes with ->first() it does work I already tried this, but I need more than just one record... how could I loop to get my result?

Comment: Using a standard `foreach`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to retrieve a model property from a collection object. The error is thrown because the collection doesn't cotain a `userId` property. You have to iterate the data in order to get it.

But this is not what you're trying to achieve. You want a json response with only those fields. So, first of all you have to change your query or to map your collection in order to select only those fields... Since you want a JSON Response, the easiest way to achieve your goal is by using [Api resources](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-resources)

So you declare your resource:

```php
namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class Player extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'userId' => $this->userId,
            'userName' => $this->userName,
            'userVote' => $this->userVote,
        ];
    }
}
```

and return this resource as a collection from your controller:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Resources\PlayerResource;
// [...]

public function index(Request $request)
{

    $room = $request->input('sessionId');

    $currentPlayers = Player::where('userSession', $room)->get();

    return PlayerResource::collection($currentPlayers);

}
```

and Laravel will do all the magic for you encoding the result in a json format.

Comment: Okay, I made a resource and now I have a Players.php in my App\Controller\Resources folder... what do I have to declare at the beginning in order to use "return PlayerResource::collection($currentPlayers);
"?

Comment: `use App\Controller\Resources\PayerResource`, i'll edit the example so you have the complete answer

Comment: Okay I added everything succesfully, now my error is: "Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::$sessionId" [same when commenting sessionid, username or userVote out]

Comment: I don't see `$sessionId` variable in your query code... This problem is not related to the code I wrote to help you.

Comment: well laravel highlights this as an issue bro```public function __get($key)
    {
        return $this->resource->{$key};
    }```

Comment: Yes but from the `\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` class... And this means that you have a wrong model declaration or you're running a wrong query somewhere else in the code... And without a full stack trace it's hard to say

Comment: My Player Model is actually empty - what do I have to fill in? I just defined everything in my migrations & controllers [App\Player.php]

Comment: So you didn't define the relation between player and session? That's the problem... You're trying to access a property that is not part of your model... You have to define the [relation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: I added now:
`namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Player extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [];

    public function sessions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Session');
    }

    
}
----- other model
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Session extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [];

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Player');

    }
    public function creator()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Player', 'userId');
    }
}` 
how to proceed?

Comment: Now you should be able to access the `sessionId` property by iterating the results of the session models related to the player... If not please ask a new question here in SO. The problem related to your question is solved, so if you find my answer correct please mark it and upvote.

And by the way IMHO, if you don't know how Laravel works there's the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs) as well as tons of guides online, first of all [Laracast](https://laracasts.com/) with its courses... You can't pretend that people here is SO can write your code